# SQL Server 2008: NULL Indexed Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What happens if a column that is indexed contains a NULL value?

Comment: What of it? What makes you think that `NULL` will behave any differently from any values in an index?

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` behaves like any other value in SQL Server indexes. There can only be one such value in a unique index (on one column). It sorts to the beginning of the table. You can seek the index on the `NULL` value as well (`myIndexedCol IS (NOT) NULL`). And you can join on `NULL` using the index using more elaborate syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL MEAN NO VALUE`

By default, null value won't be indexed.
But still I would suggest to have some filtered index like `WHERE column IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372(v=sql.100).aspx for more info

Comment: Null is indexed on SQL Server, not on Oracle.

Comment: I made it as filtered index for the column but while updating the records from the front end I am getting the following exception. "DELETE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ARITHABORT'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations."

Comment: Try enabling this option:
**SET ARITHABORT ON** and
**SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON**
Just before your delete procedure.